# Get specific data as well as all data posgresql query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table article where I need to get specific article if provide article name or id. For instance I have article name `demoarticle`, if I pass "demo" then I should get all demo alike name article and if I pass id of specific article id I should get a specific id. I have below query where I am getting alike name and all data but I pass title is ""(empty) and id is 8 then I should get 8 number article only not all article data.

```
SELECT * FROM public."Article" WHERE a_title ilike '%%' OR a_id = 8;
```

Comment: better use function for this requirement instead of plain SQLquery

Comment: You should not have percentage symbol in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have percentage symbol in the query to get only a_id = 8 records.

```
SELECT * FROM public."Article" WHERE a_title like '' OR a_id = 8;
```